# Convert an incoming ajax array to a multi dimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an php array like this

```
Array ( [ord['ord1'][0]] => shirt [ord['ord2'][0]] => pant)
```

I would like to make it like the below

```
Array ( [ord] => Array ( [ord1] => Array ( [0] => shirt ) [ord2] => Array ( [0] => pant ) ) )
```

Please let me know how I can i achieve this when you get a chance.

Comment: print_r the ajax response, show it.

Comment: @Kris Roofe , that is a print_r of the Ajax response

Comment: @KrisRoofe     {"ord['ord1'][0]":"shirt","ord['ord2'][0]":"pant"}

Comment: @Kris Roofe {"ord['ord1'][0]":"shirt","ord['ord2'][0]":"pant"}

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: @Kris Roofe    very nice, thank you very much bro :)

Comment: Yeah, glad to helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You key string is `ord['ord1'][0]`, you have to parse it.

check the [**Live demo**](http://[ord['ord1'][0]])

```
<?php
$array = json_decode( '{"ord[\'ord1\'][0]":"shirt","ord[\'ord2\'][0]":"pant"}', true);
$result = [];
foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
  $keys = explode("'", str_replace(['[', ']'], '', $k));
  $arr = [];
  $ref = &$arr;
  while($key = current($keys))
  {
      $ref = &$ref[$key];
      next($keys);
  }
  $ref[] = $v;
  $result[] = $arr;
}
print_r($result);
```